# How to get a list of used DLLs?

Tags: delphi, dll, delphi-xe2, dll-injection

I would like to get a list of used DLLs from application itself.
My goal is to compare the list with hardcoded one to see if any DLL is injected.
I can not find any examples in Google.

Comment: You could use Process Explorer (http://technet.microsoft.com/de-de/sysinternals/bb896653.aspx). It lists all DLLs as open files.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use PSAPI for this. The function you need is [`EnumProcessModules`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682631.aspx). There's some [sample code on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682621.aspx).

The main alternative is the [Tool Help](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686837.aspx) library. It goes like this:

- Call `CreateToolhelp32Snapshot`.
- Start enumeration with `Module32First`.
- Repeatedly call `Module32Next`.
- When you are done call `CloseHandle` to destroy the snapshot.

Personally, I prefer Tool Help for this task. Here's a very simple example:

```
{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

uses
  SysUtils, Windows, TlHelp32;

var
  Handle: THandle;
  ModuleEntry: TModuleEntry32;
begin
  Handle := CreateToolHelp32SnapShot(TH32CS_SNAPMODULE, 0);
  Win32Check(Handle <> INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE);
  try
    ModuleEntry.dwSize := Sizeof(ModuleEntry);
    Win32Check(Module32First(Handle, ModuleEntry));
    repeat
      Writeln(ModuleEntry.szModule);
    until not Module32Next(Handle, ModuleEntry);
  finally
    CloseHandle(Handle);
  end;
  Readln;
end.
```

Comment: I think it should be `Win32Check(Handle<>INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE);` 
instead of `Win32Check(Handle<>0);`

Answer (score 1):

Install Jedi Code Library (http://jcl.sf.net)

It has an exceptions reporting dialog which includes stack trace, Windows/hardware brief, and - the list of loaded DLLs and their versions. You can copy or call that part, generating this list, out of it.

Answer (score -1):

If you want a non-programmatic solution, just run the app under the [Dependency Walker](http://www.dependencywalker.com/).

It will not only show static dependencies but will also trap and track dynamic loading of modules at runtime and let you know which module called `LoadLibrary`.

Comment: @FreeConsulting AFAIR tdump doesn't monitor your exe for dynamic loads, it just does the statics. Has it changed?

Comment: Ah, sorry, when I see "Dependency Walker" I'm thinking older MS PSDK tool.