# How can a heap corruption be done with pure Delphi code?

Tags: delphi, heap-corruption

A customer reported a very weird problem. On one specific computer, our Delphi 12 application is terminated by Windows with a FaultTolerantHeap error which can only be seen in the Windows Event Viewer, since the application just closed without any error message. It happened a few times, but it cannot be reproduced reliably.

```
Fault bucket 1800708316894836483, Typ 4
Event Name: APPCRASH
Response: Not available
Cab Id: 0
Problem signature:
P1: Contoso.exe
P2: 9.0.1.1
P3: 659fea29
P4: StackHash_2f9c
P5: 10.0.19041.3996
P6: 39215800
P7: c0000374
P8: PCH_AF_FROM_ntdll+0x000000000009DB34
P9: 
P10: 

Failure bucket 2083737153543537444, Typ 5
Event Name: FaultTolerantHeap
Reponse: Not available
Cab Id: 0
Problem signature:
P1: Contoso.exe
P2: 9.0.1.1
P3: 659FEA29
P4: ffffbaad
P5: 
P6: 
P7: 
P8: 
P9: 
P10:
```

---

I need to understand: ***What exactly is a heap corruption and how can I enforce such a corruption with pure Delphi code?***

As far as I understand, heap corruption can be caused by a memory write overflow that can overwrite the gaps between data (which might contain management data such as the length of the heap elements). As illustrated in this [YouTube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=S-4j2Byi8KM&ab_channel=JacobSorber):

[image: The Stack]

So, I want to try if I can enforce a heap corruption:

```
type
  TMyObject = class(TObject)
    // These variables should be on the heap
    myvar: array[0..10] of char;
    myvar2: array[0..10] of char;
  end;

procedure TryToCorruptTheHeap;
var
  myobj: TMyObject; // The object reference should be on the stack
begin
  myobj := TMyObject.Create;
  ZeroMemory(@myobj.myvar[0], 2000000); // Try to destroy sections between heap entries to corrupt the heap
end;
```

Unfortunately, I only receive an error message telling me about an access violation, but the application is not terminated by the operating system:

[image: Access Violation]

No matter how hard I try, I cannot force my application to be abnormally terminated by Windows without an error message. ***So I wonder, is it possible at all to cause such a crash with pure Delphi code? Or is it rather likely that a Windows/Driver/Hardware bug or even a compiler bug caused this?***

---

***A few additional thoughts and things I have tried:***

(1) On my development computer, I already ran the application through Microsoft Application Verifier and no memory or heap issues were found.

(2) I also tried using FastMM4, since it also recognizes some memory problems.

(3) Another thought was that my application is loading a DLL file from a third party which might mess with the memory. If such a DLL were written in a low-level language like C, I could imagine that it could easily corrupt the memory. However, all my loaded DLLs are Microsoft DLLs, and I am not aware that I am dynamically loading anything else (I searched for `LoadLibrary` to be sure about this).

[image: Binded DLLs]

Comment: Try adding madExcept to your application. It has a number of feature to detect memory issues (like buffer overflow/underflow, accessing destroyed objects, freed memory,....)

Comment: It is possible that that some third party process injects some code into your application. You might be able to detect this by listing the loaded libraries during your program execution [How to get a list of used DLLs?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21180310/3636228). But there are also other methods of detecting code injection. I suggest you also read [How can DLL injection be detected?](https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/q/2262)

Comment: Or EurekaLog;-)